# Django - Order by a GenericRelation count

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stories')
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Like is just a simple model that uses Django's content type framework:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    target = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

All I want to do is order my stories by most liked, but I am unable to do so. I've tried the following with no avail:

```
stories = Story.objects.annotate(count=Count('likes')).order_by('-count')
```

This is my output:

```
>>> Story.objects.values('id').annotate(count=Count('likes')).order_by('-count')[:5]
<QuerySet [{'id': UUID('00feaa91-28b7-46c9-8755-7368408f195e'), 'count': 0}, {'id': UUID('02b8167c-19c2-41f8-819b-d0043ea03a65'), 'count': 0}, {'id': UUID('042215b0-69be-402e-9f31-8097f3a0c1c6'), 'count': 0}, {'id': UUID('0a3cb717-54e0-49d7-b0f0-e19cffb28df9'), 'count': 0}, {'id': UUID('0b4230f9-67e7-4cc1-a8bd-8b5c3c8b0917'), 'count': 0}]>
>>>
```

Which is weird, because I have stories with likes...

Which is weirder is this:

```
>>> Story.objects.aggregate(Count('likes'))
{'likes__count': 0}
>>>
```

But I know for a fact that some stories have likes:

```
>>> Like.objects.count()
9
```

I've only liked stories so far.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: what you get currently?

Comment: I updated my question with an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this. 1st pic attach is Story table and 2nd one is like table.
Mention that: I use id field value in `int` just for easy understanding. You can easily use UUID as your primary key
[image: story table]

[image: like table]

In query:

```
>>> stories = Story.objects.annotate(count=Count('likes')).order_by('-count')
>>> stories.values('count')
<QuerySet [{'count': 3}, {'count': 2}, {'count': 1}]>
>>> for story in stories:
...    print(story.count)
...    
3
2
1
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I updated my question with additional details

Comment: Ok, this is crazy, I changed from UUID to ID and it worked, but UUID doesn't work. The problem is with the UUID, might be a bug in Django?

I will stick with ID for now, but can you try with UUID?